# Notation with projective special linear group

Tags: group-theory, notation

I am bit confused with the notation $PSL(2, 7)^5$. I'm not sure what the '5' actually represents for the projective special linear group $PSL(2, 7)$

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a footnote?

Comment: Could it mean $PSL(2,7)\times PSL(2,7)\times PSL(2,7)\times P SL(2,7)\times PSL(2,7)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, most possibly but it seemed really vague to me. It has that $PSL(2, 7)^5$ has $2^5$ conjugacy classes

Comment: Perhaps that means at least $2^5$ conjugacy classes.

Comment: Can you give a link to where you came across this?